# How to autoresize a Static Cell in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView in here i fill my cells (static) with text i get from a database. The problem is i don't know how much text i'm going to get so i can't set a fixed value.

Code like :

---

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

---

Doesn't work for me because this is for Dynamic Prototype cells.

Example of my app (as for as i got for now)
http://grab.by/CgiQ

Anyone knows how to solve this? (Btw i'm working in swift and this is a requirement)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use a static cell if you have dynamic content?

Comment: I need this because it's easier than dynamic in this example. I have a array that I get from my database. When they click on one title they are forwarded to the static table with more information about that for example a description.

I added a screen so it's more clear

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if static cells can handle UITableViewAutomaticDimension. It seems as if it can't, so I strongly suggest that you actually make a dynamic prototype so you can take advantage of the iOS8-feature with automatic dimensions.

Although, it should probably work the good ol' way by using

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is Objective-C but there's obviously a swift-version of that delegate method aswell.

There you return the actual height of each row. To calculate the height of the row, use something like `yourNsString.sizeWithFont(...)`

I will not give you any code for this sizeWithFont due to the fact that I strongly dislike this approach. As you see, this gets more complicated than just using Auto-height, so your argument that it's easier with static cells is not valid anymore. Also, if you got dynamic fonts and such it will get even more complicated.

My approach is: Just put some dynamic prototypes in there and you should be good to go!

Comment: Okay, i will try to use dynamic cells but can you make a title in one cell? like statics cells does?

Comment: It's called section headers. You can do everything that you can do in static cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag control into your dynamic cell, you can certainly add a label as title